# Problem in jQuery and XmlHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to call a PHP page with XmlHttpRequest (AJAX). My problem is that I have jQuery (javascript) included in my PHP page like this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
   // my jquery code here
</script>
```

When I call the PHP page with XmlHttpRequest it fails! That is, the response only shows the PHP content but jQuery is not working! When I access that PHP page directly it works.

So, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add more details. Post javascript code and define what 'jquery is not working' is.

Comment: @testkhan: we need more details.  Most importantly, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have your jquery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(
      function() { //something magic }
);
```

The fact is: it won't fire if you load it through AJAX.

To run it, you simply have to remove the `$(document).ready` part.

You might also read [a discussion about it](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/3d25dc3f469d33b9).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot be loaded via a xmlHttpRequest call as the javascript is registered during the page load, you need to load all javascript during the initial load

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax calls should invoke a php file that only outputs json. Then your ajax success handler can use that json to run whatever javascript you need

```
--ajax.php -- no JS or jQuery allowed here, just echo json
<?php
echo json_encode(array('message'=> 'Ajax is fun'));
?>

--page.html
$.get('ajax.php', function(data) {
  console.log('Ajax call returned', data.message);
})
```